# How to get the instance of an fragment view from another

Tags: android

I'm tryin to get the instance of an activity view from another. in the first fragmment i've try to do a function that return me the instance of the view but the app crashed after that.

```
 public View getV(){

   return  this.getView();
}
```

and in the second i do :

```
   RFragment f = new RFragment();
   View v = f.getV();
```

Still not workin :/. So any help please thanks !

Comment: "not workin" > LogCat or actual/expected behaviour. I'm guessing that once you provide that, the code you are showing will not be enough to identify the problem. Also, I don't think that the whole thing is a good idea, Fragments should be made independent from each other whenever possible. Couldn't you just call a method inside RFragment that handles all the work instead of getting a reference to its view ?

Comment: Can i directly do fragment.getView(); from an activity ?

Comment: What I’m doing is that I’m inflating two fragment header and footer like that `View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_header_fragement, null); View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_footer, null);`  I’m trying to find a way to pass not the xml layout but the instance of the view of those fragments.

Comment: You could but I fear that just instantiating the fragment will not be enough and this will return null if the Fragment has not been added to an Activity, thus having executed onCreateView and being able to return something meaningful in getView... Again, this is probably not a good idea either, see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity for details.

Comment: If you actually are from Lyon, send me a hangout request through G+ (you'll find my contact on my profile page), and we can chat in french about what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61840/discussion-between-2dee-and-lyonnais655).